# ILMerge hangs on merge

Tags: .net, ilmerge

I am using ILMerge to combine 9 .NET DLL's written in C# .NET 4. The problem is ILMerge gets stuck, no error message or anything.

The log shows that ILMerge merges all the assemblies correctly, then sets out to write the target assembly. It runs the assembly resolver for a bunch of references and then.. nothing. After successfully resolving System.Configuration the log shows nothing else.

The program continues to use the CPU but I don't see if it's doing anything.

Any one else had a similar experience?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Looks like just writing out the question helped.

Turns out I needed to add `/targetplatform:v4` to the command. My guess is it's because some of the assemblies use .NET 4 and some use .NET 2.

Comment: I was attempting to merge two v4.6 assemblies and ran into the same problem. I used the recommendation above as-is (:v4) and it worked. Looks like several of our projects have a reference to a 2.0 version of the Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.

Comment: You are my hero for today

Comment: Ditto. I came across the simpler answer first, but marked this up.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing problems with ILMerge hanging, but using [IL Repack](https://github.com/gluck/il-repack) instead with the same arguments seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: Along with specifying the /lib switch to cure that error, your answer fixed my problem.