# VisualStudio 2010 PostBuildEvent ilmerge

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, frameworks, ilmerge

I am trying to merge a single .dll into the .exe by using the PostBuildEvent property..

I did put ilmerge.exe in my Windows folder

```
ilmerge /out:$(TargetDir)BootModeTest.exe $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll
```

I am getting PostBuildEvent faild with error code '1" Unspecified Error. I did build my project with .Net Fraemwork 4.0. Is this the issue? Any insight would be awesome!

Comment: specifying .Net 4 framework does not work ether. ilmerge /targetplatform:v4 /out:$(TargetDir)BootModeTest.exe $(TargetPath) $(TargetDir)Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary.dll

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions listed on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2556048/1505426