# How to compile single library from C# and VB.NET sources?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, compilation

I have two source files: first in VB.NET, second is in C#.
These files are automatically generated from some database. In .vb file some class is defined, let's say VB_Class_A; in .cs file a class is defined, that is derived from VB_ class: CS_Class_A : VB_Class_A. For compiling I first call vbc.exe with /t:module and get VB_code.module; then I call csc.exe with /addmodule:VB_code.module and get final dll. But this dll is dependent on VB_code.module: if I delete VB_code.module dll won't work. The question is how to compile independent library?

Comment: Why is it bad to have two libraries?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556048/how-to-integrate-ilmerge-into-visual-studio-build-process-to-merge-assemblies

Answer (score -1):

There is a better and easier to do this. You can convert the Visual basic code to c# or vice versa.

You can use this: converter.telerik.com

Decompiling with ILSpy can convert the code if you choose the opposite language.

Comment: Not sure converting source code is better _or_ easier.