# Dynamic Link Library - include NuGet package libraries in final DLL in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

Let's say I have created a DLL called final.dll.
In this project of final.dll I have to include another DLL, using NuGet package manager; DllToInclude.dll.

I would like to have my final.dll to embed the DllToInclude.dll.
If I have that, I only need to copy that one final.dll and include that dll in the project where I need my custom dll.

Would that be possible? Or is that bad practice after all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556048/how-to-integrate-ilmerge-into-visual-studio-build-process-to-merge-assemblies

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, this is what I was looking for.